# How to cross lava?

Tags: dark-souls-3

Whats the best way to cross the lava in the Smouldering Lake area?

I have tried using Red Bug Pellets and fire resistance gear. But it's not enough to get me back in one piece.

Lava:

[image]

Comment: +1 for screencap with a gesture that really captures how frustrating this is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have the right idea... just keep stacking.

[Bug pellets](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Red+Bug+Pellet), best FIre resist gear you have***, [all resist ring](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Speckled+Stoneplate+Ring), [fire resist ring](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Flame+Stoneplate+Ring), probably the best one though is the [pyromancy flash sweat](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Flash+Sweat).

Additionally, make sure you're embered for the higher HP.  If you have the attunement slots/faith make sure you equip and cast a HP regen spell prior to entering the lava, and be ready to chug those flasks.

Another suggestion was to equip (and raise) a high fire resist shield prior to entering the lava, this will help mitigate additional damage until you lower it for your first heals/rolls.

---

*** while keeping your equip load < 70%, but preferably < 30% for the best rolls.

Answer (score 0):

I tried stacking fire resistance, but in the end this doesn't matter that much.

The way to go is embering up and then just run through the lava and keep drinking estus. No neat trick here to get to those items (except the fire resi shield, but in the end this also results in running through the lava and keep drinking estus).